# MinMax scaler inverse_transform function not working , returns wrong values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, batch-normalization

I have a two dataframes X and y like below and i applied MinMaxScaler before training the model and after model predictions when i use inverse transform function on predictions output ,it is returning  wrong values.Please suggest and help me on this.

DataFrames :

```
               X_train                      y_train       

       0      1      2      3   Customer   0      1
0   855.0  989.0  454.0  574.0        A  395.0  162.0
1   989.0  454.0  574.0  395.0        A  162.0  123.0
2   454.0  574.0  395.0  162.0        A  123.0  342.0
3   574.0  395.0  162.0  123.0        B  342.0  232.0
4   395.0  162.0  123.0  342.0        B  232.0  657.0
5   875.0  999.0  434.0  564.0        B  345.0  798.0
             X_test                      y_test       

       0      1      2      3   Customer   0      1
6   999.0  434.0  564.0  345.0        A  798.0  815.0
7   434.0  564.0  345.0  798.0        A  815.0  929.0
8   564.0  345.0  798.0  815.0        A  929.0  444.0
9   345.0  798.0  815.0  929.0        B  444.0  554.0
10  798.0  815.0  929.0  444.0        B  554.0  395.0
11  815.0  929.0  444.0  554.0        B  395.0  768.0
```

MinMaxScaler code:

```
x_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = x_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train = y_scaler.fit_transform(y_train)

X_test = x_scaler.transform(X_test)
y_test = y_scaler.transform(y_test)
```

when i check x_train scaled values for first column, the output is like below

```
x_scaler.inverse_transform(X_train)[:, [0]]
85.50000e+6  
98.900000e+6 
.
.
.
.
.
81.50000e+6
```

Using trained model for predicitions and inverse_transform() returns output like below:

```
y_pred = model.predict(X)
y_pred = y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)

ypred:
 array([[12904402. , -30409036.
         12904402. , -30409036.
         12904402. , -30409036.
           .             .    
           .             .    
         13138567. , -29944956.]])

y_orig = y_scaler.inverse_transform(y)
y_orig:
   array([[648098.49138977. , 574631.85284378
              574631.85284378 , 409695.94

               .             .    
               .             .    
             79269.39. , 1883819.85]])
```

NOTE: the length of values in the data could range from 0 to 5.Please help me on this

[2]:Transforms features by scaling each feature to a given range.

This estimator scales and translates each feature individually such that it is in the given range on the training set, e.g. between zero and one.

```
The transformation is given by:

 X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
 X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
 where min, max = feature_range.

 The transformation is calculated as:

 X_scaled = scale * X + min - X.min(axis=0) * scale
 where scale = (max - min) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
 This transformation is often used as an alternative to zero mean, unit 
 variance scaling.
```

Comment: Sometimes you have `X_train` with capital "X" and sometimes `x_train` with small "x". That can be your problem, as one of them can be "leftovers" from previous attempts.

Comment: @Aryerez , Thanks for the reply ,i have checked mostly it is not the issue and do u have any idea wt could be other scenarios to come across such kind of wrong outputs

Comment: When I run `x_scaler.inverse_transform(X_train)[:, [0]]` after using your preceeding code, I got `array([[855.], [989.], ... [815.]])`, and not your `85.5e+06, 98.9e+06 etc.`. Maybe try to close the kernel and restart it.

Comment: i published sample data ,i'm using scaler on lakhs of data and the data is not constant like above 3 digit , it changes from 3 to 5 digit numbers.have u come acrossed any kind of issue like above anytime

Comment: It doesn't matter what data you have. When you do `fit_transform` and then `inverse_transform`, you have to get back your original numbers, whatever they were. And if you get 85.5e+06, that is 8,550,000, instead of the original 855, you have a problem there. And as I said, I run the code you posted here, and got the right results. So either you still have an upper-lower-case issue (which killing and restarting the kernel would show you), or you are doing some data manipulation not shown here.

Comment: i have edited the question a bit to show you what i'm exactly doing , is there any problem in the above code now